# Error While Compiling In Remix During Tutorial

Tags: remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, compiler

During a tutorial on my first compile I received this error: 
[image: Compiler Issue In Pink]

:1:1: Parser error: Expected import directive or contract definition.
pragma solidity ^0.5.12; 
^

What's that about? How do I fix it? I'm an absolute beginner with ready to make his first dapp with illustrated assets and marketing ready to go.

Mentors and partners welcome.

Comment: select your compiler version on the right side

Answer (score 4):

You need to choose the right compiler version.

On the right sidebar you can see your current compiler version.

The compiler version must match the number used in the `pragma solidity`!

Expand the dropdown and choose `0.5.12 nightly`.

You should probably downgrade to a full commit version like `0.5.11 commit`.

I hope this helps!